# Type Mismatch error 13 when getting length of value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim mm As String
Dim lstRow As Integer
Set ws1 = ast.Sheets("Exit")
lstRow = ws1.Range("S" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To lstRow
    **If Len(ws1.Range("S" & i).Value) = 6 Then**
        mm = Left(ws1.Range("s" & i).Value, 3)
        ws1.Range("T" & i).Value = mm
        ws1.Range("T" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

I am going to take 3 alphabet of S column value and bring out these alphabet into T column with red color. But I am facing type mismatch error in ** line. ast is file name and ws1 is worksheet name.

Comment: What appears on the Immediate Window if you put `Debug.Print Len(ws1.Range("S" & i).Value)` just before the problem line?

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me at all... still try to change all your "integer" to "long" [Why Use Integer Instead of Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#2640952)... there may be a silent overflow... also try a `Debug.Print ws1.Range("S" & i).Value` in front of your error-line... if there is no error, then `Len` can't error (in theory)

Comment: @Smandoli just a hint: in the direct window, you can use `?` in place of `Debug.Print` :)

Comment: I have changed data types integer to Long but till now its showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess this might have somethign to do with it?

```
 Dim lstRow As Integer
```

VS

```
 lstRow = ws1.Range("S" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

is it a range or an integer? the line debugs on you b/c its told to look at it one way but youre using it in another way

Comment: `ws1.Range("S" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is a numerical value. It returns the the row NUMBER for the given address. ;)

Comment: good catch. I thought for some reason it was more obvious than it actually was :/